# How to add horizontal scroll to Pandas Style in Jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

```
import pandas as pd

>>> d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4], ... , 'col20': [5, 6]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> df
```

In above example I have horizontal scroll, but

```
>>> df.style
```

no scrolling.

How can I add it to work with a lot of columns and use style formatting?

**Update**

[image: Have scrolling]

[image: No scrolling]

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you need to modify the `pd.options.display.max_columns`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(2,200)))  
df
```

[image]

Now, let's modify the max_columns parameter

```
pd.options.display.max_columns=300
df
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Works for df, but not for >>> df.style

Comment: @DmitryD can you add complete code include your output to the question?

Comment: added output to the question

Comment: Okay... what interface are you using?  This doesn't look like Jupyter notebook to me. is it?

Comment: This is Datalore, but with Jupyter kernel the same issue

Answer (score 1):

The addition of `pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)` does not work with pandas styling.

You would need to add css block containing `overflow: auto`and adjust width `width: 500px` as per requirement.

Below is a sample code block:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display, HTML

custom_styling = [
        {
            "selector": "th",
            "props": [
                ("background", "#00abe7"),
                ("color", "white"),
                ("font-family", "tahoma"),
                ("text-align", "center"),
                ("font-size", "15px"),
            ],
        },
        {
            "selector": "td",
            "props": [
                ("font-family", "tahoma"),
                ("color", "black"),
                ("text-align", "left"),
                ("font-size", "15px"),
            ],
        },
        {
            "selector": "tr:nth-of-type(odd)",
            "props": [
                ("background", "white"),
            ],
        },
        {"selector": "tr:nth-of-type(even)", "props": [("background", "#e8e6e6")]},
        {"selector": "tr:hover", "props": [("background-color", "#bfeaf9")]},
        {"selector": "td:hover", "props": [("background-color", "#7fd5f3")]},
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(2,200)))  
s1 = df.style
s1.set_table_styles(custom_styling)
s1.hide(axis="index")
# NOTE: Adding div Style with overflow!
display(HTML("<div style='width: 500px; overflow: auto;'>" +
             s1.to_html() +
             "</div>"))
```

[Output (Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVEyL.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
```

Comment: Works for df, but not for >>> df.style